# How to fix gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/<key>.gpg': resource limit

Tags: ppa, gpg, apt

I frequently receive errors as follows while running `apt-get update`:

```
[...] 
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/pdfmod-team-ppa.gpg': resource limit 
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/rael-gc-scudcloud.gpg': resource limit 
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/voldyman-markmywords.gpg': resource limit
```

The above keys are just examples and not limited to those programs. It occurs generically with all software that I added from a PPA.

Comment: Curious, how do you add the PPA normally?

Comment: This looks like an issue where there are too many keyrings, and there are instructions to fix it over on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/522747/24819).

Comment: @rifsta With `add-apt-repository -y ppa:<ppa-name>`.
@LewisGoddard I found another solution suggesting to use [launchpad-getkeys](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1263540/comments/26). Should I add it below as an answer myself?

Comment: @orschiro yes, I think you should.

Comment: It worked. Before that I tried to import keys manually with no success.

Comment: What do you mean by it worked?

Comment: Could you confirm which answer worked by clicking the check mark next to them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1263540).

Someone suggested this:

> The solution that worked for me was emptying `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`, running apt-get update, and then manually adding every key it blocked on to the main `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` keyring with `apt-key adv` as described above.

So run these commands

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d.backup
sudo mkdir /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d
sudo chmod 755 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d
```

and add each key again with this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install launchpad-getkeys
launchpad-getkeys
```

where you replace the hash with your needed key's hash.

Comment: I just added an option to use `launchpad-getkeys` which if you do a `hexdump -C` on the binary you can see it is just a loop of `apt-key adv ...`.

Answer (score 2):

One may try [launchpad-getkeys](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/automatically-import-all-missing.html).

1. Delete all the contents in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`.
2. Add `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` repository
3. `sudo apt-get update` your local database
4. Install `$ sudo apt-get install launchpad-getkeys`
5. Run `$ sudo launchpad-getkeys`
6. Check `$ sudo apt-get update` if the error is gone.